# website does not work without default.aspx

Tags: asp.net, .net, iis, web-applications, telerik

I have developed Telerik based web application.While testing on local host (running directly from .NET ) it works fine. but when hosted under IIS it does not work as expected.

we have a default.aspx page on root , and we have added a user control(login) on it . 
when accessing the site without default.aspx (http://mywebsite.com) nothing works. page is loaded correctly and it is posted back on the server when clicking a button on the page. button functionality is not performed.

but when accessing the page with default.aspx (http://mywebsite.com/default.aspx) it works absolutely fine.

I googled this problem but did not find much help. Some blogs suggest that it might be related to Extensionless url.

help will be much appreciated . Thanks.

Comment: Have you checked what is happening in Fiddler? Is it redirecting from / to /default.aspx?

Comment: need to check it , will be back soon.

Comment: when I write url without default.aspx fiddler shows host as brigdev.com and url as /. but when i write url with default.aspx fiddler shows host as brigdev.com and url as /default.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue was related to Telerik rad compression. To resolve the issue I did following:
in `web.config` , under `system.webserver` set `preCondition="managedHandler"` for `RadCompression` and `RadUploadModule`. Also, set `runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="false"`.

Reference: See known issues section : 
[http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/compression.html](http://www.asp.net/whitepapers/aspnet4/breaking-changes#0.1__Toc256770154)

See the detailed reasoning of the error:
[enter link description here](http://www.asp.net/whitepapers/aspnet4/breaking-changes#0.1__Toc256770154)

Comment: Please accept your own answer so the question isn't shown as unanswered. There is usually a delay before you can do this, so you might need to try tomorrow.

Answer (score -1):

You need to define in IIS default document. I think that if you have a root , and in root 
you defined Default.aspx, and in child site you do not have default.aspx, you need to define in webconfig of the root as wroted below.

[See the link](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/rakkimk/archive/2007/05/25/iis7-how-to-configure-the-default-document-of-the-website-in-its-web-config.aspx)

Do not forget to restart IIS. In command line , write "iisreset".

Comment: You don't need to restart the `IIS` for any change in `web.config` file. When ever you change your `web.config` file you application get started automatically. You shall recycle you pool.

Comment: You write , but sometimes config changes do not apply untill I restart IIS

Comment: I don't agree on this if you make any changes on `web.config` file you don't need to restart you IIS. If you restart your `IIS` all application in the server will be started and all the session of all the application will be lost. User will be thrown to the loging page for every application.

Comment: In root webconfig ? How did you define it ?

Comment: my page name is default.aspx , and it is set as default document in IIS. by root i didnt mean that i have two sites. I meant that my default page is in the root, it is not in sub folder inside my site.